# C# Regular Expression Optional Named Group

Tags: c#, regex

I have this pattern:

```
 string ISLTokenPattern = @"\d+:(\s+)?(?<local>\d+)[-][>](\s+)?(?<remote>\d+)\s+(?<wwn>..:..:..:..:..:..:..:..)\s+\d+\s(?<name>.+)\s+[s][p]:\s+\w+.\w+\s+\w+[:]\s+\d+.\w+\s+((?<trunk>TRUNK))?\s";
```

I have this input:

```
  1:  0-> 20 10:00:50:eb:1a:11:e3:4e 105 cwymdsae05      sp: 16.000G bw: 64.000G TRUNK QOS CR_RECOV FEC 
  2: 21->  5 10:00:50:eb:1a:12:a1:d3 108 cwymdsae08      sp: 16.000G bw: 96.000G TRUNK QOS CR_RECOV FEC 
  3: 32->  0 55:0e:b1:ae:a0:20:0e:46 160 fcr_fd_160      sp:  8.000G bw:  8.000G 
  4: 33->  1 55:0e:b1:ae:a0:20:0e:46 160 fcr_fd_160      sp:  8.000G bw:  8.000G 
  5: 66-> 46 10:00:50:eb:1a:11:e3:4e 105 cwymdsae05      sp: 16.000G bw: 64.000G
```

On RegExStorm.Net the pattern matches all 5 lines of input.  Usually if something works there, it works in C#.  In my code, the match fails on lines 3, 4 and 5.  If I take off the

```
((?<trunk>TRUNK))?\s
```

at the end lines 3, 4 and 5 match, but lines 1 and 2  fail.  I need it to match both.  As a workaround I have 2 patterns and test for 2 matches, but I'd rather do a single pattern and 1 test.

Here is the code that does the match:

```
  string ISLTokenPattern = @"\d+:(\s+)?(?<local>\d+)[-][>](\s+)?(?<remote>\d+)\s+(?<wwn>..:..:..:..:..:..:..:..)\s+\d+\s(?<name>.+)\s+[s][p]:\s+\w+.\w+\s+\w+[:]\s+\d+.\w+\s+((?<trunk>TRUNK))?\s";


 if (RegexExtensions.TryMatch(out tokenMatch, line, ISLTokenPattern)
        {
            string local = tokenMatch.Groups["local"].Value;
            string remote = tokenMatch.Groups["remote"].Value;
            string wwn = tokenMatch.Groups["wwn"].Value.ToUpper();

            string name = "";
          if (tokenMatch.Groups["name"].Success)
           {
              name = tokenMatch.Groups["name"].Value;
            }
```

Here is the RegExtension Class I wrote.  This program parses text files and I do a lot of matches so wanted something that could match and test for success in one step to keep the code cleaner.

```
 public static class RegexExtensions
{
    public static bool TryMatch(out Match match, string input, string pattern)
    {
        match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
        return (match.Success);
    }

    public static bool TryMatch(out MatchCollection match, string input, string pattern)
    {
        match = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
        return (match.Count > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `((?<trunk>TRUNK))?\s` ... what does this actually match in .NET regex?

Comment: On RegexStorm.Net it and in my code matches "TRUNK " in the input.  If the word "TRUNK" isn't there in the input the match fails.

Comment: I don't understand your regex pattern, but ending it in `(?:TRUNK .*)?` should work.

Comment: Don't get held up clinging to the current regex, just adjust it until it works in your .NET code.

Comment: that ending does work, as does simply (TRUNK)? but I need the "TRUNK" captured as an optional named group.  I can either make it an optional group or named. I can't seem to figure out an optional named group.  I'm not clinging to the current regex, since it doesn't work.  :)

Comment: Can you possibly share with us the CS code where you're doing the matching?

Comment: `\s+((?<trunk>TRUNK))?\s` ... here is a problem: If `TRUNK` be absent, then your regex will insist on finding _two_ or more spaces at the end.  But your text only has one space.

Comment: @ChrisCruz - I added it to the question. I don't think the code is the problem, I use it extensively elsewhere and it works.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - thank you.  I changed the end to (\s+(?<trunk>TRUNK))? and that worked.  If you post it as an answer I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible issue I notice with your current regex is the ending:

```
\s+((?<trunk>TRUNK))?\s
```

This matches, at the end of the regex, one or more spaces, followed by an optional named capture group for `TRUNK`, followed by a *single* space.  Note that your log lines which do *not* have `TRUNK` (possibly followed by other text) only have one space.  But the pattern is expecting two or more spaces.  The solution you used, namely removing the final `\s` might work.  But you could also move the space inside the optional captured group, i.e.

```
\s+((?<trunk>TRUNK\s))?
```

This would optionally match `TRUNK` followed by a single space.  Which you use depends on your actual data.